# NET4 features: should casting generic IEnumerable<T> to IEnumerable<MoreSpecificT> be possible?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, mono, covariance

If I have this internal method in a .NET 4 library (running on Mono here):

```
protected internal IEnumerable<KSComponent> GetComponentsByType(Type componentType)
{
    return this.componentsDic [componentType];
}
```

And I would like to expose it with a generic parameter for simple usage. This is what I have done so far and what is working:

```
public IEnumerable<TComponentType> GetComponentsByType<TComponentType>() where TComponentType : KSComponent
{
    return this.GetComponentsByType (typeof(TComponentType)).Cast<TComponentType>();
}
```

However, shouldn't with .NET 4.0 this also work:

```
public IEnumerable<TComponentType> GetComponentsByType<TComponentType>() where TComponentType : KSComponent
    {
        return (IEnumerable<TComponentType>)this.GetComponentsByType (typeof(TComponentType));
    }
```

**EDIT:**

`KSComponent` is the base class, `TComponentType` can be (e.g.) `KSMoveComponent`, which subclasses `KSComponent`.
The situation I have is that the class where the code above is from holds a list of `KSComponent` for a specific type, so for instance:

`typeof(KSMoveComponent)` maps to a `List<KSComponent>()`. All elements of the list are actually of type `KSMoveComponent`. So I'd like to have this `List<KSComponent>` being cast to `List<KSMoveComponent>` directly instead of using the `Linq.Cast()` extension.

It's coming down to the question: I have list of cars and I can be 100% sure they all are Mercedes - why can't I get a list of Mercedes then? :-)

Answer (score 1):

Covariance allows you to cast enumerable to its more generic version.

The generic condition on the other hand allows you to replace the generic type with something more restrictive.

So why would it work? It seems like the 2 of them are going in 2 different directions - no?

Comment: I edited my question. Seems like covariance has nothing to do with that case.

Comment: It still isn't going to work what if I call `GetComponentsByType<MySuperDuperSpecificImplementationOfKSComponent>()`? You're now casting `IEnumerable<KSComponent>` into `IEnumerable<MySuperDuperSpecificImplementationOfKSComponent>` how can the compiler guarantees that **each member** of `IEnumerable<KSComponent>` is of type `MySuperDuperSpecificImplementationOfKSComponent`?

Comment: It cannot, that's why I want to use an explicit cast. It has to trust me and of course the cast can fail. After all, I can use Linq.Cast< MySuperDuperSpecificImplementationOfKSComponent>().